# Select one value if two are present

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with, let's say, 3 columns: Store, Product, Status
Table, in some cases, returns 2 rows for one store and product but with different status:

```
Store  Product  Status
120    255      SYSTEM
120    255      USER
```

What I want to do is to get a row with USER if both are present (USER and SYSTEM), but if only one Status is present, I want to get a present one.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use grouping and the `max` aggregate function:

```
select store, product, max(status) as status
from t 
group by store, product;
```

This will get you the only present row if there's only one, or if there is both USER and SYSTEM present in the group you will get the USER row(s) (as USER is sorted after SYSTEM).

Comment: This one looks legit. I wonder what should I do if in the future, there will be another status which won't start from U, but this is for other topic.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Store, Product, Status 
FROM TABLE T1
WHERE 1 = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE T2
WHERE T1.STORE = T2.STORE AND T1.PRODUCT= T2.PRODUCT)

UNION

SELECT Store, Product, Status 
FROM TABLE T1
WHERE 1 < (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE T2
WHERE T1.STORE = T2.STORE AND T1.PRODUCT= T2.PRODUCT)
AND STATUS = 'USER'
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
SELECT TOP 1
    Store ,
    Product,  
    Status,
FROM
  YourTable
ORDER BY CASE WHEN Status = 'USER' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
```

Comment: While this would work for a single product it wouldn't work if there are more than one product/store combination as it only ever will return one single row.